# Intentionally craft a 180 to 255 bits Integer that bypass this miller‑rabin test with having a known factor

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers

I’ve a signature system using modular exponentiation where having the exponent being a composite with a known factor allows to forge signatures…

In order to check if the exponent is a prime number, the Integer has to pass 27 rounds of miller‑rabin (**though with always using the same base**) : if it is found to be composite, then the signature is rejected.

Now, there’s lot of saying on how unlikely it is for having such a number to be a composite while passing so much rounds of miller‑rabin tests… **But is their research on Intentionally building/computing a composite number that would bypass the miller‑rabin test with such number of rounds** ?

```
uint constant miller_rabin_checks = 28;

// Use the Miller-Rabin test to check whether n>3, odd is a prime
function miller_rabin_test(uint256 n) public view returns (bool) {
    require(n > 3);
    require(n & 0x1 == 1);
    uint d = n - 1;
    uint r = 0;
    while(d & 0x1 == 0) {
        d /= 2;
        r += 1;
    }
    for(uint i = 0; i < miller_rabin_checks; i++) {
        // pick a random integer a in the range [2, n − 2]
        uint a = (uint256(sha256(abi.encodePacked(n, i))) % (n - 3)) + 2;
        uint x = expmod(a, d, n);
        if(x == 1 || x == n - 1) {
            continue;
        }
        bool check_passed = false;
        for(uint j = 1; j < r; j++) {
            x = mulmod(x, x, n);
            if(x == n - 1) {
                check_passed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!check_passed) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And if yes, how to do it ?

Comment: Carmichael numbers see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1528789/338051 and http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/mcs425-s08/handouts/Rabin-Miller.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka the system in my case enforce exponents having a size within a specific range. That doesn’t seems be applicable to my case with so much miller‑rabin rounds.

Comment: http://www.s369624816.websitehome.co.uk/rgep/cartable.html

Comment: @kelalaka and even from you link, `260849323075371835669784094383812120359260783810157225730623388382401` which is Carmichael number is recognized as a composite by 27 rounds of the miller‑rabin test (no false positive).

Comment: Random question (that has nothing to do with the question you asked): what signature system are you using where a composite exponent makes it vulnerable?

Comment: @poncho derived from the adaptative root problem : If you don’t know the factors of the modulus, having an exponent that is a multiple of the base allows to have a predictable output regardless of the modulus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Miller-Rabin tests are being computed for random bases, then there is very little chance as at least seventy-five per cent of possible bases will fail for any given modulus. If the bases of the Miller-Rabin tests are fixed and known however, then adversarial pseudo-primes can be constructed. The method for constructing such pseudo-primes is given in Arnault's paper [Constructing Carmichael numbers which are strong pseudoprimes to several bases](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81930829.pdf). Note that this also applies when the bases are selected "at random", but the "random" selection of bases is predictable. This was exploited by Albrecht et al in the [Prime and Prejudice](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749) paper.

In the case of the code provided, the bases are determined after the candidate (and their choice is seeded by the candidate value) so these methods cannot be used.

If you are prepared to use a more naive search, my best advice is to pick odd values of $k$ such that $(6k+1)$, $(12k+1)$ and $(18k+1)$ are all prime and set $n=(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ (there should be about $2^{76}$ or so candidates). For such numbers the base $a$ will provide a false positive if $a^{9k}\equiv\pm 1\pmod n$, which will be the case for  1/8 bases. Thus each candidate has a one-in-$2^{3\times 28}$ of passing 28 rounds for a roughly 1/256 chance of finding a pseudo-prime of the required form. This is a significant amount of work, (say a few months/years of the global Bitcoin network), but likely cheaper than the estimated $2^{112}$ operations required to factor a 2048-bit number using the general number field sieve.

Comment: I have some control in the output : the random number is not only predictable based on the result of the modular exponentiation but can also be modified to some extent (most bits of the exponent are left modifiable and don’t have to match the randomly generated number). **Hence why I was interested in knowing how to craft/compute a false positive without considering the random part**.

Comment: `In the case of the code provided, the bases are determined after the candidate (and their choice is seeded by the candidate value) so these methods cannot be used` the input `n` doesn t change accross loops, so it always pick the same base. There s no problems trying to find an Integer billions times. *This doesn t change anything?*. It seems to be a better choice than factoring a 2048 bits modulus.